# Laravel Relationships and Pivot

Tags: laravel

I have a users table
id
role_id
"other standard auth stuff"

I also have a roles table 
id
role

I do not want to change the users table in the sense that its currently doing all the auth stuff provided with laravel 5.4 but

I have users with a role. Let's say coach and player are 2 types of roles and I need to now allow coaches to add players and players to add themselves to coaches and have them related.

Is it possible to relate the User model role type coach and role type player in a separate table like coaches_players without creating new models for Player and Coach? If so can someone point me in the right direction. I know if I were to start from scratch I would have Player and Coach related through belongsToMany etc. but everything in my system works off of user_id and I do not want to change all the Auth functionality etc.

1. Is there a way to create those Player and Coach models that extend User and create the relationships through those?
2. Is there a way to relate 2 columns in the User table through a pivot table coaches_players?

Just looking for some guidance and possibly some links if you have them off the top of your head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do this. Just create `coaches_players` table and define new relationships in `User` model:

```
public function players()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'coaches_players', 'coach_id', 'player_id');
}

public function coaches()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'coaches_players', 'player_id', 'coach_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try. I tried going down the inheritence route but couldn't get it working. I'll give this a go!!

Comment: Question: where do I denote the role_id or role name from the roles table. The User record includes a role_id in the User table

Comment: @Mudd you don't need it for the relationships.

Comment: So when a coach creates a new player (user) how do I add the user_id of the coach in the coaches_players table column coach_id and the user_id of the player in the players_coaches table column player_id? I get Call to a member function attach() on null when trying 
$user->save();
$user->coaches()->attach($user->id);

Comment: @Mudd `$coachUser->players()->attach($playerId)`